# I have a cron job running a casperjs file - executes fine (writes to log) but why doesn't the cron output the expected json?

Tags: json, bash, shell, cron, casperjs

**The situation:** in my crontab, I have a job that runs a .sh script. This script in turn executes my, say, casperjs casper.js - all works fine. The script executes when I run it from the command line. The shell script, when called from the command line, executes fine. I run the job from crontab and output to a log file, I can see that it's working.

However, I never get the expected output: ie. casper_output.json, here is the complete *casper.js* file that runs:

```
 var casper = require('casper').create({
    waitTimeout: 10000,
    stepTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
    //debug, write out results, errors
    logLevel: "debug",
    loadImages: true,
    loadPlugins: true,
    pageSettings: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        webSecurityEnabled: false
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function() {
        this.echo('** Wait-TimeOut **');
    },
    onStepTimeout: function() {
        this.echo('** Step-TimeOut **');
    }
});

//vars for this page
var url = 'http://urltoscrape.com';
var results = [];
var menuResults = [];
var fs = require('fs');
var terminate = function() {
    this.echo("Exiting..").exit();
};

var getContent = function() {
    //grab the values that we need for json file, store in empty results array
    var results = [];
    var URL = document.querySelectorAll('#results .event-details-link');
    var title = document.querySelectorAll('#results h3');
    var date = document.querySelectorAll('#results span');
    var desc = document.querySelectorAll('#results p');

    for (var i = 0; 
        //count through URL, title, date and description
        i < URL.length 
        && i < title.length 
        && i < date.length
        && i < desc.length;
        i++) {
        var innerURL = URL[i].getAttribute("href");;
        var innerTitle = title[i].innerText;
        var innerDate = date[i].innerText;
        //messy regex, TODO: make more efficient
        var newDate = innerDate.replace(/\s[at].*$/g,"");
        var strip = newDate.replace(/[on]/g,"");
        var nows = strip.replace(/\s/g, "");
        var innerDesc = desc[i].innerText;
        var dept = "Dept";
        //push into json, TODO: order
        results.push({ URL: innerURL, title: innerTitle, date: nows, desc: innerDesc, dept: dept});        
    }
    return results;
}

var processPage = function() {
    //crude but waits for page to load
    this.wait(2000, function() {
        //run the get content function
        results = this.evaluate(getContent);
        require('utils').dump(results);
        //write to file
        fs.write("casper_output.json", JSON.stringify(results, null, '  '), 'w');
    });
}

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.waitForSelector('#results', processPage, terminate);
});

casper.run();
```

The shell script that calls it, *casper_run.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/output/of/path/MAMP/Library/bin
PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs ; /usr/local/bin/casperjs /Applications/AMPPS/www/test/casper.js 2>&1
```

And, finally, in my crontab:

```
* * * * * /Applications/AMPPS/www/test/casper_run.sh
```

Any insight on why that casper_output.json does not write from my cron job (but does when run from command line) would be so welcome. I have been researching this for far too long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cron (or rather CasperJS) probably doesn't have write permission to write into the current working directory.

You can [change the working directory](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/change-working-directory.html) through PhantomJS' file system module or you can use a full path:

```
fs.write("/Applications/AMPPS/www/test/casper_output.json", JSON.stringify(results, null, '  '), 'w');
```